# What other times has a Chinese high-altitude balloon entered US airspace?

Tags: airspace, balloon

In an [AP news article](https://apnews.com/article/politics-montana-state-government-china-2a539a80a4a8473f102bd4ed66496d19) there's a quote from a politician stating:

> “This is not the first time a Chinese balloon has entered American
> airspace over sensitive national security areas,” Daines said in a
> Friday statement to the AP. “I don’t think anyone believes this was
> merely a civilian aircraft.”

Of course trying to google for these other events only turns up pages and pages of results about this latest incident in 2023 so I'm curious as to the other occasions mentioned in the quote.

Comment: different but related: [To what extent is modern "maneuverable spy balloonery" really a thing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/97368/14213)

Comment: In this season of the year every balloon released in the eastern/northern hemisphere that flies that high would end up in the US.

Comment: In WWII, the Japanese released a number of FuGo balloon bombs (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fu-Go_balloon_bomb) with high explosive devices attached (it was assumed), to attempt to start forest fires. Most landed in forested areas in the NW but did little damage.

Comment: this former CIA agent also mentions "there have been Chinese balloons that have flown over the United States in recent years" after about 04:50 https://youtu.be/RWn9L6x6qGA?t=290 and DW News mentions an earlier balloon during the previous administration https://youtu.be/kpD9LYP-41I?t=168

Comment: The largest part of UFOs seen by military are balloons. They are classified as UFO/UAP (unidentified aerial phenomena) since this is what they are until identified. According to the [2022 US report on UAP](https://www.dni.gov/index.php/newsroom/reports-publications/reports-publications-2023/item/2354-2022-annual-report-on-unidentified-aerial-phenomena),  510 sightings were analyzed, to find 163 balloons. They can't be attributed to one state, nor can't be sorted by missions, unless shooting them down, with the associated consequences.

Answer (score -1):

At this time this appears to be misinformation spread deliberately by the current administration. No evidence has been presented to support the assertion that this happened previously, and multiple high ranking officials from the previous administration [deny the existence of prior balloon incursions](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/trump-top-national-security-officials-refute-claim-chinese-spy-balloons-transited-us-under-last-admin).

Comment: I do not see why we should care what Trump or his national security advisors think about balloons.  If there was a Chinese balloon in US airspace, why would they even be told about it?  It's not an important event.  Spying happens all the time.